# typeahead sending request but not displaying results fetched

Tags: jquery, typeahead

This is the code that I used and tried working it out for 4 hours ,an ajax request can been seen that brings jason reults but they are not suggested in the input field

```
$('#user-search').typeahead({
name: 'user-search',
remote: '/search.php?query=%QUERY' 
});

var student = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: 'php/search_groups.php',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
  }
});

student.initialize();

$('#students').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'students',
  displayKey: 'value',
  source: student,
});

<div class="form-group">
      <label for="tags">
 Assign To</label>
       <input  id="students" type="text" class="typeahead form-control" value="" name="students" placeholder="Specify for special students" />
</div>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: I just found out that the type ahead is not working because i am using it inside bootstrap  modal if any one has suggestion  its more than welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
 var students = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name);},
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  valueKey: 'name',
  remote: {
    url: 'php/search_groups.php?search=%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY',
    filter: function (students) {
      // Map the remote source JSON array to a JavaScript object array
      return $.map(students.data, function (student) {
          return student;
      });
    }
  }
});
student.initialize();
```

To assign Typeahead to a input you can do:

```
$('.add-employment-city').typeahead({
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 1
    },{
      name: 'students',
      displayKey: 'name',
      source:students.ttAdapter(),
    });
```

In PHP file you should put this:

```
$search = $_GET['search'];
$students = //USE YOUR SQL CODE TO SEARCH

return json_encode(['data'=>$students]);
```

Tip:Put the result name in plural (students), because you frequently will receive many results.

Comment: thanks a lot , this plugin just brain stormed me, i didn't implement your code completely but the hints were helpful type ahead team improve documentation or you will loose popularity